# Configurable polling interval with angular and rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, ajax-polling

I am trying to create continuous polling using rxjs and angular. Below is an implementation of my requirement.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sq3ke5

```
ngOnInit() {
    const bitcoin$ = this.http.get('https://blockchain.info/ticker');


    this.polledBitcoin$ = timer(0, this.timeInterval).pipe(
        merge(this.manualRefresh),
        concatMap(_ => bitcoin$),
        map((response: {EUR: {last: number}}) => {
          console.log(new Date() +" >> " + response.EUR.last)
          return response.EUR.last;
          }),
      );
  }
```

However in this example, I have added polling interval and I want it to be updated based on the value entered by user. However any changes in text input is not getting reflected in polling interval. 
Can someone help me achieve this result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to be updated? The interval? like: 5000 -> 10000?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, this looks like the code is sourced from https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-polling/. 
The question is asking how to reset the poll timer to the new input value.

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the `timeInterval` variable will not simply update your `interval` Observable, you will have to kill it and start a new Observable.

Try this approach:

```
<input [ngModel]="timeInterval" (ngModelChange)="changeInterval($event)" />
Bitcoin price: {{ dataToShow }}


ngOnInit() {
  this.startInterval();
}

startInterval() {
  const bitcoin$ = this.http.get('https://blockchain.info/ticker');
  this.polledBitcoin$ = timer(0, this.timeInterval).pipe(
      merge(this.manualRefresh),
      concatMap(_ => bitcoin$),
      map((response: {EUR: {last: number}}) => {
        console.log(new Date() +" >> " + response.EUR.last)
        return response.EUR.last;
        }),
    );

    this.sub = this.polledBitcoin$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataToShow = data;
    });
}

changeInterval(e) {
  this.timeInterval = e;
  if (this.sub) {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
  this.startInterval();
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4n29cm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**Edit**

A more performant approach would be to wait for the input to change and then re-create the interval again. I have used a Subject for listening to the changes in the input, wait for some time so that the user has finished typing and then restart the interval.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.startInterval();
  this.inputSub = this.inputSubject.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('restart now')
    if (this.intervalSub) {
        this.intervalSub.unsubscribe();
    }
    // you probably don't want an interval running in zero second interval
    // add more checks here if you want, for example: this.timeInterval > 200
    if (this.timeInterval) {
      this.startInterval();
    }
  })
}

startInterval() {
  const bitcoin$ = this.http.get('https://blockchain.info/ticker');
  this.polledBitcoin$ = timer(0, this.timeInterval).pipe(
      merge(this.manualRefresh),
      concatMap(_ => bitcoin$),
      map((response: {EUR: {last: number}}) => {
        console.log(new Date() +" >> " + response.EUR.last)
        return response.EUR.last;
        }),
    );

    this.intervalSub = this.polledBitcoin$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataToShow = data;
    });
}

changeInterval(e) {
  console.log("change interval called");
  this.timeInterval = e;
  this.inputSubject.next(e);
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c355ij?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts